# Get week day of current time in specified time zone

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to get the week day of the current time in a specified timezone, and without using libraries. Numbered week days or strings are both fine.

I've used this approach to switch timezone:

```
new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/Chicago"})
```

but the output is a string so I can't do date logic in it.

PS: I am on Google Apps Script, which is why I mentioned no libraries.

Comment: Just wrap it all with one more new Date()

Comment: @demkovych for me that just switched it back to local time (working with node from my terminal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use special options for that:

```
{ weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
```

to show a week day:

```
new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {day: '2-digit', timeZone: 'America/Chicago' })
```

or to show full day name:

```
new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', {weekday: 'long',   timeZone: 'America/Chicago' })
```

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting you use the [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

```js
const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
    timeZone: "America/Chicago",
    weekday: 'long',
})

console.log(formatter.formatToParts(new Date()))
// you get an array like : [{type: "weekday", value: "Friday"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/) for this. It gives weekdays from local.

```
moment.months()
moment.monthsShort()
moment.weekdays()
moment.weekdaysShort()
moment.weekdaysMin()
It is sometimes useful to get the list of months or weekdays in a locale, for example when populating a dropdown menu.

moment.months();
Returns the list of months in the current locale.

[ 'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December' ]
Similarly, moment.monthsShort returns abbreviated month names, and moment.weekdays, moment.weekdaysShort, moment.weekdaysMin return lists of weekdays.

You can pass an integer into each of those functions to get a specific month or weekday.

moment.weekdays(3); // 'Wednesday'
As of 2.13.0 you can pass a bool as the first parameter of the weekday functions. If true, the weekdays will be returned in locale specific order. For instance, in the Arabic locale, Saturday is the first day of the week, thus:

moment.locale('ar');
moment.weekdays(true); // lists weekdays Saturday-Friday in Arabic
moment.weekdays(true, 2); //will result in Monday in Arabic
```

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for an approach without a library. I'm using Google Apps Script